# Programatically expired spring session causes the rest-api user to face unexpected response

Tags: java, spring-security, interceptor, spring-session, expired-sessions

There is an adminUser `A` who can make the session of another `rest-api` user `B` expired.

```
Collection<SessionInformation> usersSessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(user, true);
usersSessions.forEach((temp) -> {
    temp.expireNow();
});
```

Now, when the user `B` tries to make any rest request **for the first time**, it gets following `200` response without any `content-type`

> This session has been expired (possibly due to multiple concurrent logins being attempted as the same user).

I wanted to send the user a proper response something like `INVALID_SESSION` with a proper `HttpStatus`, so I tried to intercept the `servlet` with a custom `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor` (which works in other scenarios), and I observed that even the `preHandle` method was not being called.

It seems that the response is being sent during the session verification process. I have no idea how does this actually work. Is there a way to get custom response? Can `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener` be useful?